# Можно ли так оформить предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение:

Расчетная схема формируется из типовых элементов проточная полость, ступень и регулирующий орган, а также их связей: диафрагма (короткий канал), пружина, чувстви­тельный элемент.

Можно ли оформить так:

Расчетная схема формируется из типовых элементов — проточная полость, ступень и регулирующий орган, а также их связей — диафрагма (короткий канал), пружина, чувствительный элемент.

Answer (score 1):

Вы обособили  с помощью тире приложения, а они должны выражаться согласованными существительными, поэтому Ваш вариант не годится. Можно вставить "таких...как": Расчетная схема формируется из таких типовых элементов, как проточная полость, ступень и регулирующий орган, а также из их связей — диафрагмы (короткого канала), пружины, чувствительного элемента. Можно также вместо тире после "элементов" поставить двоеточие

Comment: Можно вставить "таких...как":  Разве от этого не поменяется смысл?

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаемый вариант:

Расчетная схема формируется из типовых элементов: проточная полость, ступень и регулирующий орган, а также их связей: диафрагма (короткий канал), пружина и чувствительный элемент.

Comment: А разве можно ставить в одном предложении два двоеточия?

Comment: Два двоеточия - это вполне нормально.

Comment: Два двоеточия возможны, если они позволяют наглядно определить структуру предложения. В этом предложении такую структуру можно назвать параллельной, а вот постановка двух двоеточий при последовательной структуре не очень желательно (получается пояснение к пояснению), например: В саду много цветов: астр, георгинов и роз: белых, розовых, красных.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, не согласуется в падеже то, что в скобках. Напр.: Расчетная схема формируется из типовых элементов (проточная полость, ступень и регулирующий орган). А тут надо: Расчетная схема формируется из типовых элементов: проточной полости, ступеней и регулирующего органа.

Comment: Да, надо согласовать.